# Add frontend "Restore" link

Tags: front-end, trash

I am using `get_delete_posts_link($postid)` to let users send their posts to the trash from the frontend. Now I'm trying to replicate the same functionality for them to "untrash" or restore the posts as well.

`get_delete_posts_link($postid)` seems to generate a URL like this: http://mysite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=555&action=trash&_wpnonce=0d6fc30f3b

And when I go to wp-admin and look at what link the Restore link uses, it looks to be same EXCEPT that is uses action=untrash instead of action=trash.

Since there doesn't seem to be a function the mirrors the delete post link function, I thought that perhaps manually creating the URL with variables and using the "untrash" action would do it, but it doesn't seem to work that way, restoring won't work.

What's the best way to put a link to "restore" a post on the frontend?

EDIT: This is the markup I am using the create the "restore" link (not working):

```
<?php
$untrashurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-admin/post.php?post=' . $postid . '&action=untrash';
?>
<a class="db-post-link" href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url($untrashurl); ?>">Untrash</a>
```

Comment: What's failing? Is it related to the `_wpnonce` field?

Comment: When I click the link it goes to a page that says "Are you sure you want to do this?" with a link that says "try again" and then when I click "try again" it takes me back to the previous page and the post status is unchanged.

Comment: This is definitely a [nonce error](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/obscure-wordpress-errors-why-where-and-how)

Comment: trashed posts shouldnt be visible on the frontend, therefore you must have some code that lists them, can you put this in your question?

Comment: The answer below worked, but to answer your questions real quick, I am simply using a custom query to call posts with all posts statuses (including publish, draft, trash, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment above, I believe you're running into issues with the `_wpnonce` piece of the puzzle.  Looking at the code in [`/wp-admin/post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/post.php), it appears that the `untrash` instruction is checking for a valid WordPress nonce, and not getting one.

This might do the trick:

```
<?php
function wpse_95348_undelete_post( $post_id ) {
    // no post?
    if( !$post_id || !is_numeric( $post_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $_wpnonce = wp_create_nonce( 'untrash-post_' . $post_id );
    $url = admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=untrash&_wpnonce=' . $_wpnonce );
    return $url; 
}
?>
```

It uses [`wp_create_nonce()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce) to generate the nonce you need and [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) to get a proper `wp-admin` URL.

[Further reading on WP nonces](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/improving-security-in-wordpress-plugins-using-nonces)

Comment: Excellent this worked! Just wondering why wp_nonce_url() doesn't work the same way? I will read up on nonce (I'm not too familiar with it) to get that part of my skills up. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Reading the [Codex page for `wp_nonce_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url), it looks like you should be able to use `wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=untrash' ), 'untrash-post_' . $post_id )`.  I'm still fairly new to nonces, so I hadn't noticed the `wp_nonce_url()` function before.

Comment: Oh, it was probably the admin_url thing that was actually wrong I bet. Anyway, I like the function better anyway. Much cleaner!

Comment: Looking again at the call to `wp_nonce_url()` in your question, I think I see the problem.  You're not sending anything for the 2nd argument -- `$action` -- and so WP isn't able to associate the nonce you're creating with the `untrash-post_{ID}` action.

Comment: Ooooh, OK that sort of makes sense. It says that action is optional, but perhaps even being optional in needs the context in order to actually do anything.